# Applying for standard visitor visa with wife to attend a wedding in London

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have applied for a visitor visa for me and my wife at VFS in UAE. I have a stable job with steady income and I provided all the relevant documents.

1: I did a blunder actually. The tenancy contract copy of the place where I'm staying at was in Arabic and I failed to attach a translated copy. Can this be a reason enough for Visa rejection?

2: During my application online I failed to realize that my wife had to make another application. I only realized later during my appointment at VFS when they took my biometric prints only. So I quickly made an application for her using the premium lounge and told them to combine the application. Since my wife does not work or have any funds and I will be funding her expenses. I did mention this in her application. Will this cause any issues?

3: I have attached my friend's email and wedding card. Is that sufficient?

I guess I'm having post submission anxiety as stated in other posts. But I don't want the visa to be rejected after all the hard work. Please help.

Thank you all for the response.

Comment: I don't understand what help you're asking for. What's done is done, so unless you're asking for advice on submitting revised documents with the application there's little to do but wait.

Comment: As long as the visa application status is unknown I doubt any here can provide feedback. If the visa is accepted then congratulations; if it is rejected then add a picture of the rejection letter redacting all personal info and then someone might provide an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: I did a blunder actually. The tenancy contract copy of the place where I'm staying at was in Arabic and I failed to attach a translated copy. Can this be a reason enough for Visa rejection?

Yes, it can be a reason. An untranslated document is like something you never sent to them. They don't have your tenancy contract.

> 2: During my application online I failed to realize that my wife had to make another application. I only realized later during my appointment at VFS when they took my biometric prints only. So I quickly made an application for her using the premium lounge and told them to combine the application. Since my wife does not work or have any funds and I will be funding her expenses. I did mention this in her application. Will this cause any issues?

No, there are a lot of spouses that don't work and are supported by their partners. However your lack of research on the application process might translate to lack of a strength in your application.

> 3: I have attached my friend's email and wedding card. Is that sufficient?

Not on their own.

> I guess I'm having post submission anxiety as stated in other posts. But I don't want the visa to be rejected after all the hard work. Please help

You're right ;)

Comment: so what can be done at this point regarding the tenancy contract? will VFS accept it now as a single document to attach with my application?

Comment: Nothing until you get a decision or a request from them for additional documents

Comment: can they actually request for additional documents without rejecting the visa? has it happened before from the UAE?

Comment: Yes they can. I’m sure it’s the same in the UAE as well but I don’t have a proof